# bootstrap 3 - not pushing footer to the bottom of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, fluid-layout

I received a task at work to create some mini-webpage layout with bootstrap. I decided to base on already done layout (Amoeba). Here is the preview: [Amoeba bootstrap link](http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/amoeba/)

Well, on localhost almost works except one thing - footer. Just take a look on provided link and then: click Portfolio (from navigation) and then filter the gallery by Photography.
When you will scroll down you will see ugly space. And this is my issue. I dont want that. So i thought that I need a footer OR portfolio div class which will automatically resize to proper size. BUt I dont how how to achieve that. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only to change the code of modernizr slightly. Change forceHeight to false and will work good.

```
if (Modernizr.mq("screen and (max-width:1024px)")) {
        jQuery("body").toggleClass("body");

} else {
    var s = skrollr.init({
        mobileDeceleration: 1,
        edgeStrategy: 'set',
        forceHeight: false,
        smoothScrolling: true,
        smoothScrollingDuration: 300,
            easing: {
                WTF: Math.random,
                inverted: function(p) {
                    return 1-p;
                }
            }
        }); 
}
```

Comment: http://modernizr.com/docs/
http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/

enjoy the lecture :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why, but your `body` element gets some `height` inline styling. Anyways here is the solution of your problem:

```
body {
    height:100% !important; // inline styles, so you need to add "!important" here
    position:relative;
}

#footer {   
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

**You can also add `wrapper div` if you don't want to add `position:relative` and `height:100%!important` properties to your `body` element.** Just see how it works and choose a better option for you.

Comment: thank you Kamil for prompt action. It solves the issue partially (because it removes extra space from bottom but gives it into the second section.). But according to what you have said - about inline height - ive noticed its MODERNIZR library fault. removing it solved the issue (i think). for what purpose it is?

Comment: I have lack experience in Modernizr, so I can't help you with this. I'm not sure if your are changing something in your page at the moment, but i see if you just add `height: 100%!important` or `height: auto!important` to your body element now, it works fine.